# Using jQuery to manipulate xml odoo elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, odoo

I've made some new modules in my Odoo and now when each form is loading I need to manipulate the created XML elements according to its required model and my arbitrary changes or refer to some specific function for its data validation (I know there are other ways for data validation but I'm curious if it's possible to be done with jquery functions).

I've tried to add an HTML file in the view folder and write a simple script, to begin with, but I'm not sure if it's the right place or even the right piece of code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {  
        $("input").keyup(function(event){
            console.log('t');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would be glad if anyone could offer some useful answers to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize an existing form view using the `js_class` attribute, its value will be the name of an extended form view.

To bind a new event to an input, you can customize the form controller and extend the `events` mapping.

***Example:***

**1) Extend the form view:**

```
odoo.define("MODULE_NAME.custom_form", function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var FormController = require('web.FormController');
    var FormView = require('web.FormView');
    var viewRegistry = require('web.view_registry');

    var CustomController = FormController.extend({

        events: _.extend({}, FormController.prototype.events, {
            'keyup input': '_onInputKeyup',
        }),

        _onInputKeyup(ev) {
            console.log('t');
        },

    });

    var CustomFormView = FormView.extend({
        config: _.extend({}, FormView.prototype.config, {
            Controller: CustomController,
        }),
    });

    viewRegistry.add('custom_form', CustomFormView);

    return {
        CustomController: CustomController,
        CustomFormView: CustomFormView,
    };

});
```

**2) Add it to the assets entry in the manifest file**

```py
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        'MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/custom_form_view.js'
    ],
},
```

**3) Set the js_class attribute on the form view tag**

```
<form js_class="custom_form">
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's an interesting solution and maybe it'll cover some of my goals. I'll definitely try it.

Answer (score 1):

For back-office javascript, consider using the "Odoo built-in js library":

In your custom module "my_custom_module":
Create a new file /my_custom_module/static/src/js/my_customization.js:

```js
    odoo.define('my_custom_module.switch_to_gantt', function(require) {
        "use strict";
    
    var core = require('web.core');
    var _t = core._t;
    var AbstractController = require('web.AbstractController');
    
    AbstractController.include({
    
        /**
         * Original : Intercepts the 'switch_view' event to add the controllerID into the data, and lets the event bubble up.
         * Included : On switching from Kanban to Gantt view : Remove all the GroupBy Filters because it caused Error
         */
       _onSwitchView: function (ev) {
       console.log(ev.data.view_type);
            //debugger;
/* only on the specific view : gantt: */
            if(ev.data.view_type == 'gantt')
            {
/* only on the specific model : event.event: */
            if(ev.target.modelName == 'event.event')
                $('.o_searchview .o_facet_remove').click();
            }
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    
         },
    });
    });
```

And declare this asset in the `__manifest__.py` file:

```
'assets': {'web.assets_qweb': ['/my_custom_module/static/src/js/my_customization.js']}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Although it doesn't serve my exact purpose but it helped to get a grasp on the process that I should follow.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use jquery or any js library you need to put them in this file under this path /your_app/static/src/js/test.js
and the file should be like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{  
    $("input").keyup(function(event){
        console.log('t');
    });
});
```

and you need to add the assets for this work like that :

```
'assets': {'web.assets_qweb': ['/your_app/static/src/js/test.js']} #path of the file
```

> this for jquery not for building js model in odoo

Comment: Yeah I've tried this code but it works on the entire modules , like I said I was looking for a way to bond each one of these piece of changes or events to a specific model or even view . that's why I assumed maybe a script would suit better but it seems that's not the proper way right ?

Comment: yes so you need to built js model